# Combine multiple results as columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I would like to use sql queries to display "tuition" and "fees" for universities in "florida".

I used the below code to query first the tuitions, then combine with a second query for the fees. However, I am not getting the results I am expecting.

The desired result is the following:

```
>    School      |     Tuition     |   Fees
> --------------------------------------------
>   School 1     |      2000       |    50
>   School 2     |      1000       |    80
```

But I get the following result instead:

```
>    School      |     Tuition     |   Fees
> --------------------------------------------
>   School 1     |      2000       |    50
>   School 1     |      1000       |    50
>   School 2     |      2000       |    80
>   School 2     |      1000       |    80
```

I used the following query for a WordPress database. All the values for "tuition" and "fees" are contained in a table named "entity_field_number". The values are in a column named "value". Tuition and fees are differentiated by a column named "field_name". "entity_id" is the ID number assigned to the school.

Table "entity_field_number"

```
>    entity_id   |     field_name     |   value
> --------------------------------------------
>        1       |     tuition       |    2000
>        2       |     tuition       |    1000
>        1       |      fees         |    50
>        2       |      fees         |    80
```

Below is the query I used.

```
SELECT *
    FROM
       (SELECT field_number.`value` as tuition,
           posts.`post_title` as school
    FROM field_number
      INNER JOIN posts
         ON posts.`post_type` = 'school_dir'
         AND field_number.`entity_id` = posts.`ID`
      INNER JOIN field_location
         ON field_location.`province` LIKE '%florida%'
         AND posts.`ID` = field_location.`entity_id`
         AND field_number.`field_name` = 'tuition') tuition,

       (SELECT field_number.`value` as fees,
           posts.`post_title` as school
    FROM field_number
      INNER JOIN posts
         ON posts.`post_type` = 'school_dir'
         AND field_number.`entity_id` = posts.`ID`
      INNER JOIN field_location
         ON field_location.`province` LIKE '%florida%'
         AND posts.`ID` = field_location.`entity_id`
         AND field_number.`field_name` = 'fees') fees
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQLite. Which RDBMS are you using exactly ?

Comment: You don't get that result, you get four columns...

Answer (score 2):

What you did can be paraphrased as this...

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   (<sql>) tuition,
   (<sql>) fees
```

The `,`, however, is a `CROSS JOIN`.  So you did this...

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   (<sql>) tuition
CROSS JOIN
   (<sql>) fees
```

A `CROSS JOIN` takes every combination of rows from both tables *(a Cartesian product)*.

What you really wanted is an `INNER JOIN`...

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   (<sql>) tuition
INNER JOIN
   (<sql>) fees
        ON tuition.school = fees.school
```

Now, only the rows with the same school get joined.

Better still, however, is just to rework the query to join on the `field_number` table twice.  To do that you need to "alias" it each time *(to avoid ambiguity)*.

```
SELECT
    posts.`post_title` as school,
    fees.`value`       as fees,
    tuition.`value`    as tuition
FROM
    field_location
INNER JOIN
    posts
        ON  posts.`ID` = field_location.`entity_id`
INNER JOIN
    field_number   AS fees
        ON  fees.`entity_id`  = posts.`ID`
        AND fees.`field_name` = 'fees'
INNER JOIN
    field_number   AS tuition
        ON  tuition.`entity_id`  = posts.`ID`
        AND tuition.`field_name` = 'tuition'
WHERE
        field_location.`province` LIKE '%florida%'
    AND posts.`post_type` = 'school_dir'
```